# PHP Session not persisting

Tags: php, wordpress, session, session-cookies

I am trying to use PHP session to store a state that is passed through 1 time via the querystring from a referring website. The trouble is locally I can maintain this state in the session scope but it is not working the same on the production server.

Im trying to do this in Wordpress in wp-config.php at the foot of the file:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0);
session_start();
```

Starting a session that expires with the browser.
Then checking & setting for the querystring param:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['isEUStore']) && isset($_GET['store']) && strtolower($_GET['store'])=='eu') $_SESSION['isEUStore']=true;
elseif (!isset($_SESSION['isUSStore']) && isset($_GET['store']) && strtolower($_GET['store'])=='us') $_SESSION['isUSStore']=true;
```

However, $_SESSION['isEUStore'] or $_SESSION['isUSStore'] returns NULL on any other Wordpress page in the site.

Any advice? Some configuration setting that is different perhaps?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I didn't solve the issue with session being forgotten, but I found using cookies worked instead. Such as:

```
if (!empty($_GET['store']) && strtolower($_GET['store'])=='eu') {
    setcookie('isEUStore', true, 0, '/', $faco_domain);
    setcookie('isUSStore', true, time()-3600, '/', $faco_domain);
} elseif (!empty($_GET['store']) && strtolower($_GET['store'])=='us') {
    setcookie('isUSStore', true, 0, '/', $faco_domain);
    setcookie('isEUStore', true, time()-3600, '/', $faco_domain);
}
```

The cookies are not forgotten between Wordpress pages, but expire at the end of the browsing session.